# My Weather Indicator Crash at Auto Start

Tags: unity, autostart, my-weather-indicator

I installed **My-Weather-Indicator** 0.8.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 from the atareo PPA. I can launch the program from the launcher (although it's incredibly slow). I was willing to automatically start it at the startup, so I selected such option in the relevant preference tab, however, every time I turn on the computer or just log into it, I get a ***Crash Report*** stating that the application My-Weather-Indicator has closed unexpectedly (details copied below).

I checked the Startup Preferences and I did find a My-Weather-Indicator entry, whose executable command is `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator`. The corresponding *my-weather-indicator-autostart.desktop* file seems a pretty standard one.

Is there any way to make my-weather-indicator launch at the startup and have the icon in the Unity panel without manually launching the application?

Here is a snapshot of the traceback section of the crash report:

[image: crash report snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/atareao/my-weather-indicator/issues/21

"It seems setting "Auto Location" is causing crash during startup. If location is set manually, the program runs fine."